# Install ack-grep on CentOS

Tags: centos, ack

I went through fair amount of google search to install ack-grep on CentOS but I didn't find anything help. I also looked for the source codes but couldn't find it neither. Does anyone know how to install it on the OS?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you don't have the root permission, you can do as follows:

```
$ curl https://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.22-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```

or you can change to root user:

```
$ sudo su
# curl https://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.22-single-file > /bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```

Comment: Be sure to always check http://beyondgrep.com/install/ for the latest/greatest version.  The solution above is hardcoded to a specific version.

Comment: Latest ack is 2.18 and you can no longer use the "http" url, you must use https. Will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

Could be essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/23155007/35946 but [on CentOS 6.7 the answer is](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat):

```
# yum install epel-release
# yum install ack
```

Answer (score 10):

You can get it from the EPEL software repository.

From the [EPEL FAQ](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F):

For EL5:

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm'
...
su -c 'yum install ack'
```

For EL6:

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
...
su -c 'yum install ack'
```

Comment: Sweet, just tried a `yum install ack` on CentOS 6 and it "just worked" woot.

Answer (score 4):

Go to [Beyond Grep](http://beyondgrep.com/install) and look at the section titled

### Install The ack executeable

`curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.14-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3`

And replace `ack.2.14` with the current version of ack.

> You may need to create the directory `mkdir ~/bin/` first.  You may
>   also need to modify ~/.bashrc to include this new path E.G.:
>
> `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`
>   Then reload ~/.bashrc
>   `source ~/.bashrc`

Test the installation by running ack:

`rpm -qa | ack s`

This should display any installed packages containing the letter `s`.  (some linux distributions may use `ack-grep` as the command.

Comment: Latest version is 2.18, and you have to use https. `curl https://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.18-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 ~/bin/ack`

Answer (score 1):

How did you try installing it?  Are you using yum?  The package is probably not called "ack-grep", but just "ack".

The name "ack-grep" is a Debian-specific thing because there was already a package called "ack", so they called it "ack-grep" instead.  That was years ago and now they're dropping the original "ack" package and renaming "ack-grep" to "ack".

Answer (score 1):

For RedHat Enterprise just do `sudo yum install ack`